# If coupon is applied then remove selling price and use mrp price

Tags: magento-1.7

I tried,
Admin > Catalog > Manage Attributes:

Edit special_price attribute, setting "Use for Promo Rule Conditions" to "Yes"
Add special_price = 0 condition to coupon logic .

Comment: did you found solution ?

Comment: @BabyinMagento I have called 2 events  ie. salesrule_validator_process and sales_quote_collect_totals_after. In that I have customized code. But problem is that I am not able to fetch subtotal value.

Comment: you can post new question with what code you tried and what is not working......

Comment: @BabyinMagento I already posted many questions eg - From which function discount coupon value is getting subtracted from Subtotal?

Comment: okay atleast edit the question with what you tried and what issue you are getting.....